# Weblogic clustering can be used for CORBA object?

Tags: java, jndi, corba, orb

Oracle has given links for Weblogic clustering support for JNDI .
But does clustering supports CORBA object binding ?
Can we bind CORBA object using weblogic contextfactory ?